# Capture/Record Audio Input in RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, audio-recording, raspbian

I bought a USB Audio Controller for RaspberryPi, in order to capture Audio input. I already done below steps on Rasbian but still unsure about Audio Capturing.
Can you please guide me on how do I get it?

Type the following commands to install the Audio device

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

Detection Successfully by

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ amixer
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ alsamixer
```

Also configure USB Audio device to make it default

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

by adding pound/hash symbol with

```
options snd-usb-audio index=2
#options snd-usb-audio index=2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply write this command of Command Terminal, in order to record Audio

```
arecord -f cd -D plughw:0 -d 10 a.wav
```

Let me know if you get further any issue in recording sound

Comment: 'Simply' !! - with no explanation of what -f, -D, plugwa:0, -d etc. mean or what they do? I suppose it is simple if you don't mind executing random commands on trust.